# How to make a Docker VPN gateway for other Docker containers & stacks?

Tags: docker, openvpn, docker-stack

We are implementing a CI infrastructure as Docker stacks.

Some of the containers in the stacks now need to access external services, only available through an OpenVPN connection, let's say on the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet.

In order to keep containers as "single-purpose" as possible, we would ideally like to add a Docker container acting as a VPN gateway, through which other containers could talk to the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet.

This first raises a complication: a VPN client containers needs the `cap-add` of `NET_ADMIN`, which is not available in the swarm mode we are using to deploy stack. Is there a work around, appart from starting the VPN client container as standalone through `docker run`?

And more importantly, once we have the `vpnclient` container running and connected, how can we configure other containers in the swarm to actually use it as a gateway to reach all IPs on the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet?

Comment: Have you figured this out at all? I'm looking for a way to do this as well